# PySpark: How to concatenate two dataframes without duplicates rows?

Tags: pyspark

I'd like to concatenate two dataframes A, B to a new one without duplicate rows (if rows in B already exist in A, don't add):

Dataframe A:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  1
```

Dataframe B:

```
   A  B
0  5  6
1  3  1
```

---

I wish to merge them such that the final DataFrame is of the following shape:

Final Dataframe:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  1
2  5  6
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not a free coding service. SO expects you to [try to solve your own problem first]( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).  Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example[(https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [How to Ask]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4):

You have just to drop duplicates after union.

```
df = dfA.union(dfB).dropDuplicates()
```

Answer (score 3):

[`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union) and [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionAll`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionAll) seem to yield the same result with duplicates.

Instead, you can get the desired output by using direct SQL:

```python
dfA.createTempView('dataframea')
dfB.createTempView('dataframeb')

aunionb = spark.sql('select * from dataframea union select * from dataframeb')
```

Using SQL produces the expected/correct result.

Comment: @pault Tested, it doesn't introduce duplicates as a result of the SQL union. **Important:** this will keep duplicates that were already in the data frame. In fact, this may be preferred in some cases because running `distinct` after `.union` may have the **side effect of removing duplicates that were not meant to be removed**...!! That can be an easy bug to introduce...

Comment: You are correct. I misunderstood the part where you wrote *`union` and `unionAll` seem to yield the same result with duplicates.*

Comment: Or you can just do a `df1.union(df2).dropDuplicates()`

Answer (score 2):

In order to remove any duplicate rows, just use union() followed by a distinct().

Mentioned in the documentation 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

"union(other)
Return a new DataFrame containing union of rows in this frame and another frame.

This is equivalent to UNION ALL in SQL. To do a SQL-style set union (that does deduplication of elements), use this function followed by a distinct."